# Heat Transfer Rate. Find Outside Temperature

Tags: thermodynamics

I am required to find the temperature of the outside wall. I have rearranged an equation but it doesn't feel right

Ti and To are the inside and outside temperatures.

U is the overall heat transfer coefficient.

A is the surface area of the wall.

If the inside 20m2 wall at 25 degrees is subjected to a heat rate of 10 kj/s and heat is transferred at the rate of 15w/cm2, determine the temp of the outer wall.

$$\frac{dQ}{dt} = UA(T_i-T_o)$$

Where

$$\frac{dQ}{dt} = 10Kj/s$$

$$ U = 15W^o/cm^2$$

$$ A = 20m^2$$

$$T_i = 25^oC$$

First I will convert the units and use SI units.

$$U=0.015 Kj/s$$

$$A = 20*10^4cm^2$$

$$T_i = 298 K$$

Sub in numbers

$$10*10^3 = (0.015) * (20*10^4)*(298-T_0)$$

$$\frac{10*10^3}{3000}=298-T_o$$

$$3.3=298-T_0$$

$$294=-T_o$$

Clearly this is incorrect. Where am I going wrong here? I assume the units I am using are incorrect.

Comment: Cross posted here : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3445645/532586

Comment: And here https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/32036/10902

Answer (score 0):

without checking the whole calculation, there seems to be a sign error in the last line.

$3.3 = 298-T_o \\  3.3-298=-T_o \\T_O =294.7  $

It's just a small sign error.

Comment: Yeah that's it I think. If I just convert it back to Celcius then the answer makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @Zibraz313, If I answered your question then you should accept it so it becomes the accepted answer.